# Как обработать клик только на видимом изображении виджета

Tags: android

Видел много приложений, где при нажатии на разные элементы, будь то домик или дерево, выполняется определенное действие. Это ведь невидимая кнопка в форме этого объекта? Или как это вообще реализовано?

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы клик обрабатывался только по границам видимой области, а не по всей области виджета?

Comment: @pavlofff,   да, именно так

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для решения вашей проблемы нужно переопределить метод `onTouch()` для виджета, который будет содержать некоторое изображение, по которому нужно отработать клик. Например, для виджета `ImageView`:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imgView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            final ImageView img = (ImageView) v;
            final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            int x = (int) (event.getX()*bitmap.getWidth()/img.getWidth());
            int y = (int) (event.getY()*bitmap.getHeight()/img.getHeight()); 
            int color = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
            Log.i("Color",": " + color);
           return (color == 0) ? true: false;
        }
    });
```

Метод должен возвращать `true`, чтобы клик игнорировался методом `onClick()` виджета и `false`, чтобы регистрировался этим методом.
Получить текущие координаты клика можно методами `event.getX()` и `event.getY()`, соответственно для горизонтальной и вертикальной оси. Эти координаты будут соответствовать абсолютным координатам на устройстве, с отсчетом от верхнего левого угла виджета.
Получить абсолютные размеры исходного изображения можно методами `bitmap.getWidth()` и `bitmap.getHeight()`.
Получить абсолютные размеры виджета на экране методами `img.getWidth()` и `img.getHeight()`

В данном примере алгоритм определения, есть ли изображение на кликаемой области основан на том, что получаем `Bitmap` с назначенным изображением из виджета, затем определяем какой цвет (метод `getPixel()`) находится в координатах касания. Если прозрачный (color = 0), то отменяем обработку клика, если любой другой, то пропускаем.
Вычисления координат производятся по формуле, исходя из того, что `Bitmap` (исходная картинка) может не соответствовать реальным размерам виджета (например он растянут на полэкрана) и мы приводим координаты касания на виджете, к координатам на реальном изображении.

Это только один из примеров, как можно определить касание в определенной области, вы можете реализовать любой свой алгоритм, определяющий, попало ли касание в определенную область на экране или нет.

Если аналогичных виджетов будет использоваться несколько, то разумнее будет сделать кастомный `View` отнаследованный от того же `ImageView`, к примеру, в котором переопределить метод `onTouch()`.

Comment: спасибо, именно то, что хотел! а как проверить, если фон розовый или зеленый? одним словом, если не прозрачный, но известно точный оттенок?

Comment: @OleksandrZakrevskiy значение, возвращаемое методом `bitmap.getPixel()` - цвет в представлении #ARGB, то есть переменная `color` содержит код цвета по два байта шестнадцатеричного представления: альфа канал, красный, зеленый, синий. Проще всего получить нужное значение просто выводя его в лог и затем подставив в условие. Обновил код, тапая пальцем по виджету вы будете получать в логе код цвета того места, куда тапали.

Answer (score 2):

Для любой [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) можно задать `background` и навешать `onClickListener`. Будь то `ImageView` или `Button`.

Comment: Ну это понятно. Но ведь тогда кнопка будет прямоугольная, значит если нажму где-то около самого дерева, к примеру, но все еще в этой прямоугольной области, то действие произойдет. Как этого избежать? Можно ли сделать кнопку ИМЕННО в форме чего-либо?

Comment: @OleksandrZakrevskiy а вы убедились, что нажатие рядом с домиком или деревом не приводит к выполнению действия?

Comment: Убедился, приводит. Дерево то не прямоугольное и всю область кнопки не занимает.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря о чём конкретно идет речь ? Например в TextView прямо в тексте могут находится картинки и т.п. А все дело в том, что на самом деле отображается html - страница, со ссылками `<a href>` нажатие на которые и приводит к действиям