# Нужна помощь с расположением кнопок

Tags: android, xml

Есть набор кнопок, их надо расположить так как на макете.
Нужна помощь с расположением и отступлениями от центральной кнопки, важно, чтобы на разных дисплеях (планшеты, или устройства с малыми экранами), были правильные отступы.
Буду благодарен за минимальный код.

[image: макет расположения кнопок]

Comment: Это делается одним виджетом, просто рисунок с нужным видом. Потом в onTouch() этого виджета определяется место касания, например по цвету в вашем случае, и в зависимости от этого выполняются действия

Comment: Для старта посмотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541630/177345). Для селектора-индикатора нажатий можно [использовать level-list](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/drawable.php#levellistdrawable), где из onTouch() будет передаваться нужный уровень и подставляться изображение с видом нажатия на нужном секторе.

Comment: @pavlofff Есть кнопки для макета с большим расширением.
Моя функция будет получать какой-то аргумент и в зависимости от аргумента должны изменяться кнопки на макете (форма кнопок одинакова, просто другой цвет). Мне нужна помощь именно с расположением этих элементов и отступлениями.

Comment: Кнопки должны реагировать на клик по отдельности? если да, то не получится расположить их таким образом стандартными средствами , расположением и отступами и нужно делать свой виджет. Если нет или реагировать только на общее касание этого круга или если бы справа было как и слева две половинки, то это решаемо. Делайте дополнения, редактируя сам вопрос (кнопка "править" под вопросом), а не в комментариях к нему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте контрол [PieView](https://github.com/zurche/plain-pie/blob/master/plain-pie/src/main/java/az/plainpie/PieView.java), правда он кастомизирован под прОгресс, но мне кажется вполне подойдет для вас, надо будет немного переписать его - он по умолчанию всегда стартует с 0:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<az.plainpie.PieView
    android:id="@+id/pieView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    plainpie:inner_pie_padding="30"
    plainpie:percentage="75"
    plainpie:percentage_size="70"
    plainpie:inner_text_visibility="true"/>
```

Если в исходник добавить новый атрибут типа:

```
<az.plainpie.PieView
    android:id="@+id/pieView"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    plainpie:inner_pie_padding="30"
    plainpie:startPercentage="50" <!-- начало отрисовки сектора -->
    plainpie:percentage="75" <!-- конец отрисовки сектора -->
    plainpie:percentage_size="70"
    plainpie:inner_text_visibility="true"/>
```

Comment: Видимо нужна раздельная обработка клика по этим отдельным секторам, разве в этом виджете предусмотрен такой функционал? Я вообще [вот что нашел](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31001475/7566397) еще давно, но что о сильно мудрено, реализация как писал в комментарии к вопросу будет проще

Comment: Ну а что повесить `onClickListener` на каждый сектор разве это сложно? Конечно, объемного эффекта нажатия не будет, но вроде это и не требуется, тем более что сейчас это и немодно - в эру плоского дизайна :)

Comment: На каждый сектор отдельно? или как их разделить, я так понимаю нужно что то вроде круга с кнопками на пульте ТВ, каждый сектор и круг в центре выполняет свою функцию, я смутно представляю, как с помощью виджета из ответа реализовать такое. Думаете, если сделать часть дуги он будет реагировать на клик только в этой части? я думаю будет реагировать прямугольная область последнего наложенного сектора.

Comment: `PieView` он все равно ведь квадратный, внутри квадрата что-то нарисовано. Если сделать умный листенер, который будет понимать что нажатие произошло внутри закрашенного сектора - то тогда все сработает.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы елементи изменялись в зависимости от получаемого аргумента (есть нарисованные элементы макета)