# Android. Круглая кнопка по центру с вырезанным задним фоном

Tags: android, xml, button, drawable

Достаточно примитивный и легкий интерфейс - 4 кнопки, заполненные drawable xml. По сути просто прямоугольник со скругленными краями как на картинке:

[image: Текущий интерфейс]

А надо сделать вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто овал - это не сложно, а вот как сделать так, чтобы под ним был виден фон, да и еще соответствующе были обогнуты рамки других кнопок?

Answer (score 3):

Это довольно сложно на самом деле. Android не имеет нативной поддержки не прямоугольных областей касания.

Чтобы клики проходили точно по областям не квадратных кнопок, вам нужно делать одну большую кнопку со всеми 5-ю нарисованными областями и затем вешать на эту кнопку `TochListener`, где обрабатывать координаты касания и по ним определять, в области какой нарисованной "кнопки" оно было. Затем предпринимать нужные действия.

Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541630/177345) с вариантом обработки не прямоугольной области касания. Как вы организуете алгоритм определения сказать трудно, наверное лучшим решением будет матрица (двумерный массив) значений, где ее позиции - координаты на виджете, а значения - номер кнопки, то есть при клике в центр, например, в середине этой матрицы, получим значение, скажем 5, значит нажата 5-ая кнопка и тд. Матрицу можно уменьшить, чтобы она хранила значения не по пикселям, а, например для области 10x10 пикселей (все равно пальцем в каждый пиксель не попадешь), соответственно нужно будет приводить координаты в пикселях в масштаб матрицы (в данном случае делить на 10).
Также нужно учесть, что на разных экранах абсолютные коородинаты будут отличаться (то есть на экране 480х360 середина по Х  будет 180, а на экране 1080х720 это уже будет 360) и нужно преобразовывать их в относительные общих размеров виджета.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна точность в области касания, то cделай через `glGenFramebuffers` (так делают в играх).

Там есть возможность рендерить обьекты в промежуточный буфер, и по нему потом и определять id объекта. Набери Color Pick на этом сайте. Фишка в том, что визуально обьект выглядит так как надо, а в задний буфер он заливается цветом по которому его и находят при касании.

Comment: opengl используете?

Comment: там есть возможность рендерить обьекты в промежуточный буфер. по нему потом и определить id. Набери colorPick на этом сайте.

Comment: там фишка в том что визуально обьект выглядит так как надо, а в задний буфер он заливается цветом по которому его и находят при касании.

Comment: да все равно уже отминусовали :( а так хотелось помочь человеку:(

Comment: Добавьте - хорошие ответы плюсуют. Один плюс - сразу +10 вам даст ;-)

Comment: Далее в xml при помощи weight у linearLayout попадаю в область овала и внутрь этого всего ставлю, например, com.makeramen:roundedimageview, котнтур которого полностью повторяет контур получившегося овала от четырех прямоугольников, делаем отступы нужные и...вуаля! И не надо никаких opengl и т.п. Правда если нужны состояния нажатия, то придется рисовать по две картинки на каждое состояние каждого прямоугольника и овала.

Чуток позже оформлю xml и выложу сюда.

Comment: Вот кому интересно ссылка на xml. Думаю по нему все будет предельно ясно [Ссылка](https://pastebin.com/0yCT7VbK)

Comment: тоже прикольно!