# Как ставить метку в определенных координатах ImageView

Tags: java, android, app

В приложении нужно ставить случайную метку на картинку карты, которую я планировал отображать через ImageView. Я могу узнать координаты и ставить метки случайно, но проблема в том, что на изображении карты есть вода, на которую метку ставить не надо. Поэтому мой вопрос в том, каким образом мне ограничить места на картинке куда может ставиться метка ?

Comment: можно [по цвету в точке касания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541630/177345) определять

Answer (score 0):

Создаете второе изображение карты. Участки где нельзя делать помечаете удалением альфа канала. Делаете проверку в коде на альфа. Как вариант эту карту наложить сверху на голубой фон (вода), тогда обходимся 1 изображением в ресурсах.